# How to avoid code duplication when using OOP

Tags: python

The code below defines an `AppConfig` class:

```
import os 
import json 

class AppConfig(object):

    def read_config(self, name):        
        filepath = os.path.expanduser("~/%s.cfg" % name)

        if os.path.exists(filepath):
            with open(filepath, 'rb') as file:
                return json.loads(file.read())

        else:
            return dict()

    def write_config(self, name, data):
        filepath = os.path.expanduser("~/%s.cfg" % name)

        with open(filepath, 'w') as file:
            json.dump(data, file)

    def update_config(self, name, key, value):
        filepath = os.path.expanduser("~/%s.cfg" % name)

        data = self.read_config(name)
        data[key] = value

        with open(filepath, 'w') as file:
            json.dump(data, file)
```

It has three methods: `read_config`, `write_config` and `update_config`.
All three methods assemble the path to the configuration file path with:

```
filepath = os.path.expanduser("~/%s.cfg" % name)
```

There is clearly a code duplication here. How to edit this code to make it cleaner and easier to read avoiding the code duplication? What else could be done to make it more Pythonic?

Please feel free to use the code below to play with this class:

```
appConf = AppConfig()

data = {1: "one", 2: "two"}
appConf.write_config("my-app", data)

data = {3: "one", 4: "two"}
appConf.update_config(name = "my-app",  key = 3, value = "three")

conf = appConf.read_config("my-app")
print(conf)
```

Comment: If `filepath` will never change within each *instance*, what's stopping you from making it an instance variable (`self.filepath`)? Then you define it in `__init__` and use it wherever you need. And if changing `filepath` is possible (but rare), make a method that explicitly updates `self.filepath`.

Comment: Or `filepath = self._create_filepath(name)`? Also from an API perspective returning an empty dictionary for an attempt to read from a missing file seems wrong. And note that the update can use read *and* write.

Comment: Failure to use `self` in any method is a sure sign your class is poorly designed (or doesn't need to be a class).

Comment: @chepner Please clarify your opinion. It is interesting! Or better yet, please post it as an answer (so we can upvote it). I believe it is exactly what we are looking for. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Answer posted, but please just consider it a lengthy comment. It doesn't have anything of substance that isn't already in Ratnesh's answer.

Comment: (Except for my suggestion to use a `try` statement instead of `os.path.exists`; do that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current class doesn't need to exist. (We'll get to fixing the repetition in a moment, and then we *will* use your class.) Since none of your methods use `self`, and you never set any attributes on the instance of `AppConfig`, you may as well just use 3 regular functions:

```
import os 
import json 


def read_config(name):        
    filepath = os.path.expanduser("~/%s.cfg" % name)
    if os.path.exists(filepath):
        with open(filepath, 'rb') as file:
            return json.loads(file.read())
    else:
        return dict()

def write_config(name, data):
    filepath = os.path.expanduser("~/%s.cfg" % name)
    with open(filepath, 'w') as file:
        json.dump(data, file)

def update_config(name, key, value):
    filepath = os.path.expanduser("~/%s.cfg" % name)
    data = self.read_config(name)
    data[key] = value
    with open(filepath, 'w') as file:
        json.dump(data, file)

# Non-string keys will be converted to strings by json.dump
# anyway; may as well use strings to be consistent.
data = {"1": "one", "2": "two"}
write_config("my-app", data)

data = {"3": "one", "4": "two"}
update_config(name="my-app", key="3", value="three")

conf = read_config("my-app")
print(conf)
```

However: the state your class *should* be tracking is the path for a given name. When you instantiate `AppConfig`, it should compute the correct file path and save that for use by other methods, in the form of an instance attribute.

```
class AppConfig:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.filepath = os.path.expanduser("~/%s.cfg" % name)

    # Avoid a race condition by trying to open the file
    # immediately, rather than checking if it exists first
    def read_config(self, name):
        try:        
            with open(self.filepath, 'rb') as file:
                return json.load(file)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            return dict()

    def write_config(self, name, data):
        with open(self.filepath, 'w') as file:
            json.dump(data, file)

    def update_config(self, name, key, value):
        data = self.read_config(name)
        data[key] = value

        with open(self.filepath, 'w') as file:
            json.dump(data, file)

appConf = AppConfig("my-app")

data = {"1": "one", "2": "two"}
appConf.write_config(data)

data = {"3": "one", "4": "two"}
appConf.update_config(key="3", value="three")

conf = appConf.read_config()
print(conf)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `__init__`

```
import os
import json

class AppConfig(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.filepath = os.path.expanduser("~/%s.cfg" % name)

    def read_config(self):
        if os.path.exists(self.filepath):
            with open(self.filepath, 'rb') as file:
                return json.loads(file.read())

        else:
            return dict()

    def write_config(self, data):
        with open(self.filepath, 'w') as file:
            json.dump(data, file)

    def update_config(self, key, value):
        data = self.read_config()
        data[key] = value
        self.write_config(data)
```

The state your class maintains is the path to a configuration file for a given user. That state should be stored in an instance attribute, initialized when the object is created. Later method calls access `self.filepath` rather than each taking `name` as an argument and repeatedly reconstructing the path.